# Ruby - Max Array Sum from non-adjacent integers in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

This code walks through the array and returns the largest sum of non-adjacent integers. This is from HackerRank - Can anyone explain why this works? Its a solution I found online but I don't understand it and didn't figure this out myself.

Thanks!

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dynamic-programming

```
def maxSubsetSum(arr)
    incl = 0
    excl = 0
    temp = 0
    for i in 0...arr.size
        temp = incl
        incl = [arr[i]+excl, temp].max            
        excl = temp
    end
return [incl, excl].max
end

maxSubsetSum([1,3,5,2,4,6,8])
```

Comment: `for` loop, explicit `return` keyword and four spaces for indentation?  These things are considered unidiomatic.

Comment: @SagarPandya Not to mention the `return` keyword isn't even indented

Comment: Interesting. In the loop you assign temp = 0, incl = the number at particular index + 0, return and array of the value from the array + 0 and assign excl = 0. Weird

Comment: Your first sentence ends, "of adjacent integers". That should be "of non-adjacent integers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Understand the algorithm**

The code is fairly straightforward once you understand the algorithm being used. A Google search turned up many hits. See, for example, [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/). They all seem to use the same dynamic programming approach.

The general solution produces both the maximum sum and the array of elements from the original array that produce that sum. Here only the sum is needed so the solution is simplified slightly. I will first describe the algorithm for producing the general solution, then will simplify to compute only the maximum sum.

**Compute general solution**

If the array is `a`, the `n`th step computes two values: the maximum sum among the first `n` elements, `a[0]`, `a[1]`,...,`a[n-1]`, if the `n`th element is included and the maxium sum if that element is excluded. This is easy because those two results have already been computed for the previous element, `a[n-2]`. When the last element of the array has been processed the maximum sum equals the larger of the maximum sum when the last element is included and the maximum sum when the last element is excluded. To construct the array that yields the maximum sum a simple walk-back is employed.

Let `b` be an array of hashes that we will build. Initially,

```
b[0] = { included: 0, excluded: 0 }
```

Then for each `n = 1,..., m`, where `m = a.size`,

```
b[n] = { included: a[n-1] + b[n-1][:excluded],
         excluded: [b[n-1][:included], b[n-1][:excluded]].max }
```

After `b[m]` has been computed, the maximum total equals

```
[b[m][:included], b[m][:excluded]].max
```

The walk-back to construct the array that yields the largest sum is outlined in the example below.

Consider the following.

```
arr = [1, 3, -2, 7, 4, 6, 8, -3, 2]

b = (1..arr.size).each_with_object([{ included: 0, excluded: 0 }]) do |n,b|
  b[n] = { included: arr[n-1] + b[n-1][:excluded],
           excluded: [b[n-1][:included], b[n-1][:excluded]].max }
end
  #=> [{:included=> 0, :excluded=> 0},    n  arr[n-1]
  #    {:included=> 1, :excluded=> 0},    1     1
  #    {:included=> 3, :excluded=> 1},    2     3
  #    {:included=>-1, :excluded=> 3},    3    -2
  #    {:included=>10, :excluded=> 3},    4     7  
  #    {:included=> 7, :excluded=>10},    5     4
  #    {:included=>16, :excluded=>10},    6     6
  #    {:included=>18, :excluded=>16},    7     8
  #    {:included=>13, :excluded=>18},    8    -3
  #    {:included=>20, :excluded=>18}]    9     2
```

I've included `arr[-1]` for each value of `n` above for easy reference. The largest sum is seen to be `[20, 18].max #=> 20`, which includes the last element, `arr[9] #=> 2`. Hence, `arr[8]` could not be included. Note that `b[8][:excluded] + arr[8] #=> 18 + 2 => 20`, which is `b[9][:included]`.

Since `arr[8]` is excluded `arr[7]` could be included or excluded. We see that `b[7][:included] == b[8][:excluded] == 18` and `b[7][:excluded] == 16 < 18 == b[8][:exclued]`, which tells us that `arr[7]` is included. The same reasoning is used to walk back to the beginning of `b`, demonstrating that the elements that sum to `20` form the array are `[3, 7, 8, 2]`. In general, multiple optimal solutions are of course possible.

**Compute maximum sum only**

If, as in this question, only the maximum sum is required, and not the array of elements that produce it, there is no need for `b` to be an array. We may simply write

```
b = { included: a[0], excluded: 0 }
```

Then for each `n = 1,..., m-1`

```
b[:included], b[:excluded] =
  a[n] + b[:excluded], [b[:included], b[:excluded]].max
```

We may wrap this in a method as follows.

```
def max_subset_sum(arr)
  arr.size.times.with_object({ included: 0, excluded: 0 }) do |n,h|
    h[:included], h[:excluded] =
      arr[n] + h[:excluded], [h[:included], h[:excluded]].max
  end.values.max
end

max_subset_sum arr
  #=> 20 (= 3+7+8+2)
```

If desired, we can write this with two-element arrays rather than hashes (closer to the code in the question), though I don't think it's as clear.

```
def optimize(arr)
  arr.size.times.with_object([0, 0]) do |n,a|
    a[0], a[1] = arr[n] + a[1], [a[0], a[1]].max
  end.max
end

optimize arr
  #=> 20
```

Notice that I've used parallel assignment to avoid the create of a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is some pretty ugly (by ugly I mean unidiomatic) Ruby code so let's clean it up before we proceed:

```
def maxSubsetSum(arr)
  incl = 0
  excl = 0
  temp = 0
  arr.each do |value|
    temp = incl
    incl = [value + excl, temp].max            
    excl = temp
  end
  [incl, excl].max
end

maxSubsetSum([1,3,5,2,4,6,8])
```

Now we can start to analyze this code. I've gone through and written the values of each variable at each step in the loop:

```
value = 1
temp = 0
incl = 1
excl = 0

value = 3
temp = 1
incl = 3
excl = 1

value = 5
temp = 3
incl = 6
excl = 3

value = 2
temp = 6
incl = 6
excl = 6

value = 4
temp = 6
incl = 10
excl = 6

value = 6
temp = 10
incl = 12
excl = 10

value = 8
temp = 12
incl = 18
excl = 12

(return 18)
```

At any given point, the program is determining whether or not it should "use" a value -- the disadvantage to using a value is that you cannot use the value after it, as that is adjacent. At every step in the process, it's comparing adding the current value to `excl` (which represents the best sum at the previous step without including that value) with `incl` (technically `temp` but `temp` holds `incl` at that stage), which represents the value at the previous iteration of including the value.

`temp` is not remembered across loops; after each iteration of the loop, the only values that matter are `incl` and `excl`. To reiterate, at the end of each loop, `incl` holds the best sum that includes the previous number, and `excl` holds the best sum that does not include the previous number. At each step in the loop, incl and excl are re-computed to reflect the inclusion or exclusion of the new value.

To show that this process does work, let's consider the above array but with an extra element at the end, 7. So now our array looks like this: `[1,3,5,2,4,6,8,7]`. We already have most of the work done from the previous listing. We set `temp` to `18`, `incl` becomes `[7 + 12, 18].max` which is `19`, and `excl` becomes `18`. Now we can see that including this last number means that we get a number larger than the previous result, so we have to use it, and that means that we can't use the `8` we previously used to get our result.

This process is known as dynamic programming, where in order to determine the answer to the overall question, you break the problem down and add complexity to it. In this case, we break the array down and then slowly add back each value, keeping track of what the best results for the previous part are.

Comment: In step 2, how is temp = 1 and excl = 1? You never increment the values. I see this: temp = incl (0), incl = [3 + 0, 0].max, excl = 0. So how come it works?

Comment: @jedi, by step 2 you mean when value = 3, right? By the end of that iteration of the loop, `temp` gets the old `incl` value, which is `1`, and then `excl` gets the value of `temp`, which is `1` as well.

Comment: How? Step 1. temp = 0 (because incl = 0), incl = [1 + 0, 0].max, excl = 0, because temp =0. Step 2.temp = 0, because it was not incremented anywhere, incl = [3 + 0, 0].max because excl was 0 and incl was 0 and was not incremented, excl = 0 because temp was 0 (never incremented). How come temp and excl are being incremented in your code?

Comment: @jedi: What value does `incl` have at the end of the first iteration? What value is `temp` assigned at the beginning of the second iteration?

Comment: @jedi At the end of the first step, `incl = [1 + 0, 0].max`, which is `1`. At the beginning of the second step, `temp` gets assigned the value of `incl`, so it gets assigned `1`. At the end of the second step, `excl` gets the value that `temp` holds, which is `1`.

Comment: I understand it now. The variables get assigned within the loop and I was thinking for all this time that the variables were taken from outside the loop.